# Why do backslashes disappear when run through echo?

Tags: bash, echo, backslash

I have code like this, which processes a CSV file:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
    variable=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}')
    echo $variable
 done < ./file.csv
```

If the CSV file contains any `\`, when I run this command, the output text does not show the `\`.

How can I ensure that `\` is not deleted?

Comment: Try with double quotes: `"$(echo "$line" | awk -F, '{print $2}')"`

Comment: That's a backslash.  Start from the bottom.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that the `read` builtin uses `\` as escape character.  The `-r` flag disables this behaviour.

So, this should work:

```
while read -r line
  variable=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2}')
  echo $variable
done < ./file.csv
```

You should also place `"..."` around things like `$(...)` and variables, like

```
variable="$(command)"
echo "$variable"
```

Comment: Also, `cut -d, -f2` can be used instead of that `awk` command.

Comment: Your `read -r` suggestion also works for my opposite question of how to delete the \ in while loops, so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The man page for `bash` has this to say about `read`:

> The backslash character (\) may be
>                 used to remove any special meaning for the next  character  read
>                 and  for line continuation.

Answer (score 1):

Found a good reference [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.1?topic=e-echo-command):

> The \ (backslash) is a quote character in the shell. This means that
> unless the \ is used with an escape character or enclosed in quotes,
> for example "" or '', the shell removes the backslashes when the
> command is expanded.