# cannot get "\"while reading an xml file

Tags: xml, xwiki

I'm trying to read an xml page of xwiki line by line but when i read this line:

```
[[3.2.2>>doc:3\.2\.2]]
```

it returns just

```
[[3.2.2>>doc:3.2.2]]
```

any ideas why it ignores `\` .

so i have an xwiki page localPäge.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><page xmlns="http://www.xwiki.org"><content>
====[[PROJECTS>>WebHome]]/[[SCV>>SCV]]/composant1====

|=Release|=date

|[[3.3.3>>doc:3\.3\.3]]|2015-06-25:14:23:20
</content>
</page>
```

what i'm doing is just

```
while read i
do
echo "$i">>PageToSend.xml
done < localPage.xml
```

in pageToSend.xml instead of having

```
|[[3.3.3>>doc:3\.3\.3]]|2015-06-25:14:23:20
```

i have this

```
|[[3.3.3>>doc:=3.3.3]]|2015-06-25:14:23:20
```

and what i want is to keep the famous "\" .

Comment: actually when i read a line wich contain a "\" and put it in another file ,the "\" disapear.

Comment: see the edit , i can't be more clear .

Comment: Your edit is a vast improvement.  Withdrawing vote to close now.

Comment: vast improvement? i put the code that you want

Comment: Yes, "vast improvement" means "great improvement".  Your question is very well stated now.  I withdrew the close vote, withdrew the downvote, and added an upvote because it's very clear now.

Comment: ok i'm french and i tought that vast has the samle meaning in french , sorry

Comment: No problem.  Your English is better than my French, I'm sure.  I think this might help you: [Why do backslashes disappear when run through echo?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10238617/290085)

Comment: Why "it" ignores "\"? What exactly is "it"? You haven't told us what software you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238617/why-do-backslashes-disappear-when-run-through-echo  and "it" is an echo of the line