# Why does my jq / read / echo pipeline remove backslashes?

Tags: json, jq, quotes

I am trying to split a large JSON file (~4 Mio elements) into separate files (one file per element).

The file kinda looks like this:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
      "title": "Professional JavaScript - \"The best guide\"",
      "authors": [
        "Nicholas C. Zakas"
      ],
      "edition": 3,
      "year": 2011
    },
    {
      "title": "Professional JavaScript",
      "authors": [
        "Nicholas C.Zakas"
      ],
      "edition": 2,
      "year": 2009
    },
    {
      "title": "Professional Ajax",
      "authors": [
        "Nicholas C. Zakas",
        "Jeremy McPeak",
        "Joe Fawcett"
      ],
      "edition": 2,
      "year": 2008
    }
  ]
}
```

To split each book into a separate file, I am using the following command:

```sh
cat books.json | jq -c -M '.books[]' | while read line; do echo $line > temp/$(date +%s%N).json; done
```

For the last two items, everything's ok, because the book title does not contain any quotes. However, in the first one, the `\"` get replaced by `"` which leads to a broken JSON file, as the subsequent parser - of course - interprets the `"` as a boundary of an element.

I've tried to use `jq -r`, but that did not help.

I'm using the jq version shipped by CentOS 7:

```
[root@machine]$ jq --version
jq-1.6
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: FYI, best practices for using `while read` loops are covered in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). And while it doesn't make a big difference with `jq`, it's good to get out of the habit of using `cat filename | ...`; some programs (including `sort` and `tail`) can run much faster when they're given a real, seekable file handle instead of a FIFO (aka pipe) that can only be read once front-to-back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sh read command eats slashes in input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924388/sh-read-command-eats-slashes-in-input)

Comment: [Why do backslashes disappear when run through `echo`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238617/why-do-backslashes-disappear-when-run-through-echo) is another preexisting candidate duplicate (the title doesn't make it clear, but it's the same `while read; do` mistake).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `-r` option to [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read):

```
while read -r line; do echo "$line" > temp/"$(date +%s%N)".json; done
```

It prevents interpreting backslash escapes.

And you should quote your variables.

See the difference:

```
$ read var <<< 'quoted quotes: \"\"'
$ echo "$var"
quoted quotes: ""
$ read -r var <<< 'quoted quotes: \"\"'
$ echo "$var"
quoted quotes: \"\"
```

Using `-r` with `read` is almost always what you want and really should have been the default behaviour.